# Query is returning Result after too long and returning result for small data sets only. Need help in optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, query-performance

Need to Know the **Number of distinct Users who acquired a Particular Service (Entered by any User)**. Then For those users, **what were other services they have acquired** (excluding the Entered Service).(Let's say 10 other services were acquired other than the Entered one). Then, **Finally need to find out how many users were associated with these other service ?**

I have created a postgresql query. And its returning the right result. However, the problem is that the query is too slow. And runs only for Those Service_ids which have small user base. **Need help in optimization of the Following Query.**

**Postgresql Code #**

```
SELECT CAST(count( distinct sr.user) as INT) as "Unique users Acquiring Entered Service",CAST(0 as TEXT) as "Other Services Acquired By These Unique Users",CAST(0 as INT) as "Total Unique Users of These Other Acquired Services"
from public.Service sr 
where sr.service_id={{service_id}}
group by 2,3 
UNION
Select CAST(0 as INT) as "Unique users Acquiring Entered Service",CAST(B.Other_Services as TEXT) "Other Services Acquired By These Unique Users",CAST(count(distinct C.user) as INT) as "Total Unique Users of These Other Acquired Services" 
FROM 
(
SELECT sr.user as user 
from public.Service sr 
where sr.service_id={{service_id}}
) As A 
JOIN 
(
SELECT sr.user as user,sr.service_id as Other_Services 
from public.Service sr 
where sr.service_id<>{{service_id}}
) AS B 
on A.user=B.user
JOIN 
(
SELECT sr.user as user,sr.service_id as Other_Services 
from public.Service sr 
) AS C
on B.Other_Services=C.Other_Services 
group by 1,2
order by 1 desc,3 desc
LIMIT 8
```

**Output #**

```
Unique Users Acquiring   Other Services Acquired   Total Unique Users Of These
Entered Service           By These Unique Users      Other Acquired Services
2                                0                             0
0                              rcygo                         4,433
0                              qkbhX                         4,123
0                              qmBr2                         3,989
0                             sd4ifdca                       3,512
0                              rcygn                         3,244
0                              qbArm0                        2,785
0                              rbEkP                         2,706
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a db fiddle of some sort would all help.

Comment: Here is the sample data and db fiddle. The output is right, but the query is slow
https://rextester.com/BFA17259